# MVC4 Pass Model from View to Controller

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4, post, view, model

```
//Model
public class Car
{
   string name{get;set;}
   double speed {get;set;}
   //etc.
}
```

Basic model

```
//Controller
public ActionResult ModifyCar(Car c)
{
    c = GetAdditionalData(c.name, c.speed);
    return View(c);
}
```

So I'm making call to outside service to get additional data for car.

Below is the form which I'm really confused on. I am just going to write this in HTML.

But from here I'd like to take a basic empty model.. populate it then send to the controller for additional data.

```
//View
@model Car
<form id="carform" method="post" action="/Car/ModifyCar"> //Guessing
    <input id="carName"  /> //Somehow bind with @model.name
    <input id="carSpeed" /> //Somehow bind with @model.speed
    <input type="submit" /> //Somehow send the model to the controller
</form>
```

Sorry I'm not really good at the View part at all but I hope you can see where I was going here.

Also, I'm doing validation that requires a form id.. I noticed that there is no form id when using HTML Helper to make the form. Thats going to break my CSS I wrote.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
@model Car
<form id="carform" method="post" action="/Car/ModifyCar"> //Guessing
<input id="carName" name="carName" value=@Model.name  /> //Somehow bind with @model.name
<input id="carSpeed" name="carSpeed" value=@Model.speed /> //Somehow bind with @model.speed
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> //Somehow send the model to the controller
</form>
```

when your form will submit it will go to `ModifyCar` `action` in `Car`
`Controller`.

But as you has mentioned in your question that we cannot give id in html helper ,it is wrong we can for ex:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ModifyCar","Car",FormMethod.Post,new{ id="carform" }))
```

the above BeginForm() will render same html as:

```
<form id="carform" method="post" action="/Car/ModifyCar">
```

Comment: But is this "<form id="carform" method="post" action="/Car/ModifyCar">" correct? it was just a wild guesss.. and I dont see where the model is being passed back

Comment: Okay, bare with me just testing this out now. +1 for the id trick

Comment: Doesn't work. I can't bind to the value="@model.name"

Comment: Does work.. I cant believe it's that simple. It already worked. You just have to name the properties to match the model.

Comment: Yes...Happy to see that it worked for you...@Proximo